# Stack: How to check each integer(in a loop) against another integer?

Tags: java, data-structures, stack

I have to implement a program using Stack which allows a user to enter a positive integer,`n`, followed by `n` integers. Then the program should allow the user to enter another integer, `val` after which the program should display the last value which is greater than `val`. From my understanding of the program, I figured out that it should compare each element from the top of the stack to the `val`. Therefore to compare each element to `val`, it should iterate through the values in the stack starting from the top. I don't really know how to make this work so would be pleased if I could get any help. Here is my program:

```
public class MyClass{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);

        Stack<Integer> NumsInStack= new Stack<Integer>();

        int n, num, val;
        System.out.println("Please enter n.");
        n=sc.nextInt();

        for(int i=0; i<n;i++){
            num=sc.nextInt();
            NumsInStack.push(num);
        }

        System.out.println("Enter a value.");
        val=sc.nextInt();

        for(int i=0; i<NumsInStack.size();i++){
            if(NumsInStack.peek()>val)
                System.out.println("The number greater than "+val+" is "+NumsInStack.peek());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens when you run your program?  What does a debugger tell you?

Comment: Stack implements iterable interface.So get the iterator instance and iterate through.

Comment: @CPerkins It doesn't work as my code just checks if the last element is greater than `val`. If it doesn't, it terminates there instead of checking through other elements from the top and see if which one is greater than `val`

Comment: On behalf of all those who will have to read your code, please don't ever iterate over a stack

Comment: Also keep in mind the naming convention for identifiers in Java.  Specifically, variables names should not begin with an uppercase letter.  `NumsInStack` should be `numsInStack`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should never iterate over a stack, it defeats the entire purpose of choosing that data structure.  You want to use `pop` and `peek`:

```
while (!NumsInStack.empty()) {
    if (NumsInStack.peek() > val) {
        System.out.println("woot!");
        break;
    }
    NumsInStack.pop();
}
```

Since you only want it to print out the last number that is higher, you should also put a `break;` after the print statement so that it breaks out of the loop when it finds a match.  Without the break it would print all of the values that are higher.

Answer (score 1):

Working code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class MyClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        Stack<Integer> NumsInStack = new Stack<Integer>();

        int n, num, val;
        System.out.println("Please enter n.");
        n = sc.nextInt();

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {

            num = sc.nextInt();
            NumsInStack.push(num);

        }

        System.out.println("Enter a value.");
        val = sc.nextInt();

        while ( !NumsInStack.empty()){
            int stackElement = NumsInStack.pop();
            if (  stackElement > val){
                System.out.println("Stack Element > value :"+stackElement+":"+val);
                break;
            }
        }

    }
}
```